# Cannot open header file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and trying to import header files in the project, but have been failing miserably. Here is what I have tried to do:

```
#include "gevents.h"
#include "gobjects.h"
#include "gwindow.h"

int main(){

     int x=1;

     return 0;
}
```

I have added these three header files in the project location:
C:\Users\Shaby\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication39

In addition, I have also gone to Project properties ->Configuration Propertues -> C/C++ ->General and included the above path location in "Additional Include Directories" but this had yielded nothing. Instead, I am getting the following error:

*Unable to start program C:\Users\Shaby\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication39\Debug\ConsoleApplication39.exe The system cannot find the file specified*

Comment: Did it compile? If you press F7, does it give you errors?

Comment: Yes, on compiling it gives the following error: _Unable to start program C:\Users\Shaby\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication39\Debug\ConsoleApplication39.exe The system cannot find the file specified_

Comment: That message should appear when trying to run the program, not when trying to compile it. Try to compile only (Build->Rebuild Solution). In the Output window you should see a message like:
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
if there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

@Usman Khan ,
I have one solution for your problem.In Solution Explorer Window (if not opened then press `Ctrl+Alt+l`) you can see you project name.Right click on it and than `Add > Existing Item`. Now select your header files which you want to include & press `Add`. Done :) .

Comment: Have done that but still getting the same error message

Comment: Right Click on project name in Solution Explorer Window .
Click on `Set as StartUp Project`
Then build your project & run it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not having a problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

why are you making it complex, just keep it simple.After creating your project. Open solution explorer. Under your project name you would see a folder "header files" , add your header files in it (your header files should have ".h" extension) and then to use them include them in your source files

Comment: I have done that but to no avail. I am getting the same error I mentioned in the post

Comment: okay then change your path to "C:\Users\Shaby\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication39\ConsoleApplication39" because the folder has another folder inside it with the same name and header files are placed there

Comment: or try using this syntax for including your header files 
"#include <gevents>" i think this should work cuz i have faced the same problem once. Its better if you create a new project from start cuz i dont know what changes you have made in your project to fix the error. so better it is that every thing should be default.